# Simplest form of writing a byte/char sequence to stdout

Tags: c

I want to write a series of chars (bytes) to stdout with C on Windows using the Tiny C Compiler, to find out what the assembly will look like. The `printf` method would be too high-level.

I've tried following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void dumpDec(uint16_t x) {
    char buf[32];
    size_t buf_sz = 0;
    int pos = sizeof(buf) - buf_sz;
    buf[pos] = '\n';

    do {
        pos--;
        buf[pos] = x %10 + '0';
        x /= 10;
    }
    while (x > 0);

    write(1, &buf[pos], buf_sz);
}

int main() {
   dumpDec(2048);
   return 0;
}
```

compiling using `tcc.exe main.c` (no warning, no error) but it seems not to print anything at all. This `write` method seems to exists on Linux (using `<unistd.h>` which is not available for TCC), but which one to use for Windows? I've only found `io.h` to contain a definition for `int __cdecl write(int _Filehandle,const void *_Buf,unsigned int _MaxCharCount);`.

PS: Yes, I've searched the "Similar questions" section, but found no matching answer.

Comment: the `buf_sz` is 0. `write(.... but_sz);` is writing zero bytes, i.e. nothing.

Comment: Oh, it was a silly question. Really thought to have not found the correct method instead of searching the error in my buggy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two errors:

- You're storing the line feed beyond the end of `buf`.
- You're writing zero bytes to the handle because `buf_sz` is always zero.

```c
void dumpDec(uint16_t x) {
    char buf[6];                           // Enough for `65535␊`.
    int pos = sizeof(buf);
    buf[ --pos ] = '\n';                   // Added decrement.

    do {
        buf[ --pos ] = x % 10 + '0';
        x /= 10;
    }
    while (x > 0);

    write(1, buf+pos, sizeof(buf)-pos);    // Fixed write size.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the sequence:

```
    char buf[32];
    size_t buf_sz = 0;
    int pos = sizeof(buf) - buf_sz;
    buf[pos] = '\n';
```

`pos` is 32 and `buf[pos]` is out of bounds. That can be fixed by initializing `buf_sz` to 1 instead of 0.

`buf_sz` remains unchanged by the loop:

```
    do {
        pos--;
        buf[pos] = x %10 + '0';
        x /= 10;
    }
    while (x > 0);
```

So the following `write(1, &buf[pos], buf_sz);` call does not write the correct number of characters. That can be fixed by incrementing `buf_sz` in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Without buffer:

```
void dumpDecRec(int fd, unsigned dec)
{
    if(dec) dumpDecRec(fd, dec/10);
    if(dec) write(fd, (char[]){dec % 10 + '0'}, 1);
}

void dumpDec(int fd, unsigned num)
{
    if(!num) write(fd, (char[]){'0'}, 1);
    else dumpDecRec(fd, num);
}


int main(void)
{
    dumpDec(1, 0);
    write(1, (char[]){'\n'}, 1);
    dumpDec(1, 100000);
    write(1, (char[]){'\n'}, 1);
    dumpDec(1, UINT_MAX);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EznzGe1qG

If your compiler does not support compound literals:

```
static void printdigit(int fd, unsigned digit)
{
    char d = digit + '0';
    write(fd, &d, 1);
}

void dumpDecRec(int fd, unsigned dec)
{
    if(dec) dumpDecRec(fd, dec/10);
    if(dec) printdigit(fd, dec % 10);
}

void dumpDec(int fd, unsigned num)
{
    if(!num) printdigit(fd, num);
    else dumpDecRec(fd, num);
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution without buffer!